# Composed Function Support with spring cloud stream throw exception : "Queue is full: Reactive Streams source doesn't respect backpressure"

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl, spring-cloud-function

We are building event-driven microservices using Spring Cloud Stream (2.1.2.RELEASE) with Rabbit binder and facing some issues about its integration with spring cloud function (2.0.1.RELEASE).

**Our Source stream is the following :**

1. Read CSV file on SFTP server and copy it to local
2. Split local file content by line
3. Convert csv line to custom object (Using a Function)
4. Publish on built-in Source output channel

**We use the following (simplified) Java DSL to describe step 1 & 2 :**

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class SftpSource { 


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec messageSourceBuilder = ... ;
    return IntegrationFlows.from(messageSourceBuilder, c -> c.poller(...)
            .split(new FileSplitter(false));
            .channel(this.source.output())
            .get();
}
}
```

**And a function to deal with step 3 :**

```
@Bean
public Function<String, MyPojo> myConverter(){
    return csvLine -> {
        try {
            // Convert csvLine to MyPojo here
            return myPojo;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Throw custom error 
            throw new CustomException(e);
        }
    };
}
```

**In application.properties (or command line) :**

```
spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=myConverter
```

It works as expected when the file contains a few lines (even if there are some conversion errors, redirected in global error channel), but as soon as the file contains a lot of lines (containing some conversion errors), the following error is thrown :

```
2019-06-05 19:29:15.190  INFO 26096 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.c.s.m.DirectWithAttributesChannel    : Channel 'MyApp.output' has 0 subscriber(s).
2019-06-05 19:29:15.194 ERROR 26096 --- [ask-scheduler-1] 
reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1                : | 
onError(reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Queue is full: Reactive Streams source doesn't respect backpressure)
2019-06-05 19:29:15.221 ERROR 26096 --- [ask-scheduler-1] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1       
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Queue is full: Reactive Streams source doesn't respect backpressure
    at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:215) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:239) [reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblySubscriber.onNext(FluxOnAssembly.java:345) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$IgnoreSink.next(FluxCreate.java:618) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedSink.next(FluxCreate.java:153) ~[reactor-core-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:246) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:234) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:390) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.concatMap(Flux.java:3445)
    org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionInvoker.apply(FunctionInvoker.java:128)
Error has been observed by the following operator(s):
    |_      Flux.concatMap ? org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionInvoker.apply(FunctionInvoker.java:128)
```

We spent a lot of time in debugging, without success, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the first time something like this was reported. Definitely looks like a bug on our end, but would be hard to track without reproducible sample. Do you think you could possibly provide a sample project in GitHub that reproduces the issue so we can tak a look?

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of composing `myConverter` to this particular source. Aside from the fact that there is a different extension point for payload/type conversion, the real question is what do you expect next? I mean it's a source which outputs POJO which immediately will be converted back to `byte[]` and sent to the Source's destination. In other words no one seems to be consuming `MyPojo`, so why convert it?

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky thanks for reply. This component is a part of stream deployed on spring cloud data flow server. An application Sink (common to a data group) is used on the other side to consume the produced output from rabbitmq queue. We could use a Processor but we do not want to deploy an additional instance for each of our stream (we have a lot of streams we would like migrate to spring cloud stream).

Comment: We have also multiple sources types : json, csv, xml files ... from several servers SFTP/FTP. We plan to build different Source application to consume these files and convert them in common formats (common to a data group) to be consumed by a single application Sink (or multiple instances). Our goal is to compose a source with a common converter at runtime (or using application properties to choose a converter adapted to our data) without building a new application.

Comment: At the very beginning we studied the possibility of using application aggregation (as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020876/spring-cloud-stream-aggregates) to compose Source, Processor and Sink in a single application. Spring cloud function seems to be more flexible/appropriated and offers us the ability to use spring cloud data flow server.

We are trying to provide a sample project that reproduces this issue.

Comment: Jeremy, could you please raise the issue in [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) and link this thread. We'll continue to discuss there as I believe it's an actual issue that we need to address. The conversion at he Source and data flow is a side not which I will clarify as well once you move this discussion to Github

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky related issue on github : [https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1726](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1726)

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky sample project available here (we reproduced the bug using a source from spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file) : [https://github.com/jeremypicavet/spring-cloud-stream-function-sample](https://github.com/jeremypicavet/spring-cloud-stream-function-sample)